# No message error occurs MethodNotAllowedHttpException Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

I get no message error after click on submit. Here is my view, which is shown correctly.

```
   {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.invitation')) !!} 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="iduser" value="{{ $user->id }} "/>
                            <select class="form-control" name="idgroup">
                                @foreach ($groups as $group)
                                    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {{Form::submit('User einladen',['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                        </div>
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is my routes. The last one belongs to this view store.invitation.

```
Route::get('invitation', 'UsernameController@search')->name('search.username');
Route::post('invitation/result', 'UsernameController@result')->name('result.username');
Route::post('invitation/store', 'InvitationController@store')->name('store.invitation');
```

And this is my function...

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        'idgroup' => [
            'required', 'numeric', new AdminGroupRequest, new MaxInvitationAdmin
        ],
        'iduser' => [
            'required', 'numeric', new AlreadyInvitation, new AlreadyPartOfGroup, new MaxInvitationUser
        ]
    ]);

    $iduser = $request->iduser;
    $idgroup = $request->idgroup;
    $i = new Invitation;
    $i->idgroup = $idgroup;
    $i->iduser = $iduser;
    $i->active = 1;
    $i->save();

    $username = User::where('id', $iduser)->select('name')->first();
    $groupname = Group::where('id', $idgroup)->select('name')->first();

    return redirect()->action(
        'UsernameController@search')->with('success', 'Sie haben den User ' .$username->name. ' in die Gruppe ' .$groupname->name. ' eingeladen.');
}
```

EDIT: Problem is the validation. But in my view I have

```
@if(@count(errors > 0))
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                {{$error}}
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
@if(@count(errors > 0))
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

you should use

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{$error}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

or because you don't wrap errors in any container you could just use:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{$error}}
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I change it but the error is the same. When a validation error in the function store occurs, what exactly is the validation error message doing? Is it a respond back to the previous route where the request comes from (Route::post('invitation/result', 'UsernameController@result')->name('result.username');
R)? Maybe the message is giving back but with the parameter ($user, $groups) which the view needs? I think I have to design a route redirect to the route before with paramters the message is able to show? Right?

Comment: sorry without parameter, not with the parameter